# shouldn't a spam post not bump a post up after the spam post is removed?

Tags: discussion, spam

I notice this old thread [How can I migrate mails from Yahoo! Mail to Google Apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/141115/how-can-i-migrate-mails-from-yahoo-mail-to-google-apps)  got bumped up 
it got bumped up because a spam post was made. the spam post was removed but it remained bumped up.

Comment: This is probably more of a question for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as it would necessitate a change to the software underlying the site. It also feels like something that would already have been asked. Indeed there is [Unbump a question if the answer providing the bump is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/) and [Undeletion, Unbumping and the Potential For Abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283012) at a [quick search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=spam+bump)...